# Error testing DAOs: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, dao, hibernate-mapping

I am very new to Spring + Hibernate, and I am running tests to see if my DAOs are working. I get the following error which upon searching in Google yields a lot of different answers (mostly of typos, which I have checked). I'm hoping you can help me out on this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:308)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:220)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:301)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:303)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
        at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:199)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'nominationDao' defined in file [C:\IdeaProjects\Projects\branch\dev\test-dataacess\target\classes\com\dev\test\data\dao\hibernate\NominationHibernateDAO.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.dev.test.data.dao.hibernate.NominationHibernateDAO]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1003)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:907)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:900)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:455)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:84)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:280)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:304)
        ... 27 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.dev.test.data.dao.hibernate.NominationHibernateDAO]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:162)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:108)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:280)
        ... 42 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
        at com.dev.test.data.dao.hibernate.AbstractHibernateDAO.<init>(AbstractHibernateDAO.java:50)
        at com.dev.test.data.dao.hibernate.NominationHibernateDAO.<init>(NominationHibernateDAO.java:36)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
        ... 44 more
```

What could cause this? Please let me know if I have edit in my AbstractHibernateDAO and NominationHibernateDAO.

Thank you!

Edit here are the snippets:

This is a snippet for AbstractHibernateDAO, line 50 is by a comment:

```
public abstract class AbstractHibernateDAO<T, K extends Serializable>
        implements DAO<T, K> {

    protected Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Class<T> persistentClass;

    protected AbstractHibernateDAO(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) //LINE 50
                getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }
```

Line 36 is followed by a comment on this snippet for NominationHibernateDAO:

```
@Repository("nominationDao")
public class NominationHibernateDAO<T extends Nomination>
        extends AbstractHibernateDAO<T,Integer>
        implements NominationDAO<T> {


      @Autowired(required = true)
      public NominationHibernateDAO(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
           super(sessionFactory); //LINE 36
      }
```

Comment: @hvgotcodes I added snippets where the error was pointing

Comment: can you show how you are loading the application context in your junit test?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression

```
getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]
```

refers to value substituted to first type parameter of `AbstractHibernateDAO` (which in the `AbstractHibernateDAO.java` is denoted by `T`). The type substituted by subclass `NominationHibernateDAO` is still not concrete, it is `T extends Nomination`, which is definitely not a `java.lang.Class` instance, but a `Type` instance (`TypeVariableImpl` is an implementation of a `Type`).

If the `NominationHibernateDAO` was declared with something like that:

```
class NominationHibernateDAO extends AbstractHibernateDAO<Nomination, Integer> { ...
```

then the `AbstractHibernateDAO` constructor magic would work. Alternatively, you can (or you even should?) instantiate a subclass of `NominationHibernateDAO` declared like this:

```
class ConcreteNominationHibernateDAO
        extends NominationHibernateDAO<ConcreteNominationSubclass> { ...
```

or

```
new NominationHibernateDAO<ConcreteNominationSubclass>() {}
```

This, again, would not trigger the problem.

Are you sure the `NominationHibernateDAO` class is meant to be used as a Spring bean?

Comment: yes, it should. But now I think I see what you're saying... I think the problem I have is that I have a 3 different entities extending the Nomination entity, and 3 other DAOs extending from the Nomination DAO. I will look into this, but it seems that your answer was what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Just to clarify I do have the following: `public final class SpecificNominationHibernateDAO extends NominationHibernateDAO<SpecificNomination> implements SpecificNominationDAO` on 3 different separate DAOs which is similar to what you said, but I guess my implementation was a bit wrong.

Comment: I solved this by simply making `NominationHibernateDAO` an abstract class, and having a new `HibernateDAO` bean for a generic nomination, this way I can extend from `NominationHibernateDAO` comfortably while still keeping a generic version. Super simple but of course sometimes it's tough to see what's going on. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Nimchip Make the class with generic `<T extends Xxx>` abstract, and don't make it as bean, will solve the issue, it also solved my issue. You should put that conclusion as an individul answer or in the question itself, so that more people could understand it clear.

Comment: Possibly relevant: I ran into this exception when trying to examine a parameterized type (via reflection) from a constructor. Doing the same thing after the constructor had completed worked fine.