# Spring dependency injection generic service class

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, dao

i have a generic dao class and i'm trying to use spring dependency injection but i have the following error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'BaseDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.abgc.fab.dao.BaseDao]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
```

my applicationContext.xml file

```
<bean id="BaseDao" class="com.abgc.fab.dao.BaseDao">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

my basedao class :

```
public class BaseDao<TEntity> extends CommonDao<TEntity> implements IBaseDao<TEntity> {

}

 public abstract class CommonDao<TEntity> extends FabObject implements ICommonDao<TEntity> { 
       public CommonDao() { 
               Type t = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
               ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) t;           
                this.classEntity = (Class<TEntity>) pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0]; 
      }
```

any help please ?

Comment: It says something about the constructor throwing an exception?  What's the constructor like?

Comment: And the constructor of `CommonDao`?

Comment: Can you show `CommonDao` ?

Comment: also which spring version are you using?
and are you using springs auto wiring of beans?

Comment: `public abstract class CommonDao<TEntity> extends FabObject implements ICommonDao<TEntity> { public CommonDao() {
    Type t = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) t;
    this.classEntity = (Class<TEntity>) pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
  }`

Comment: You didn't think all that `Type` stuff in the base class might be important to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a deep hierarchy you'll need to use something like [TypeTools](https://github.com/jhalterman/typetools) (which I authored):

```
class DeviceDao extends BaseDao<Device> {}

Class<?> entityType = TypeResolver.resolveRawArgument(IBaseDao.clas, DeviceDao.class);
assert entityType == Device.class;
```

Note: As always, type arguments can only be resolved at runtime if they're captured in a type definition. So subclassing `BaseDao` is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Is TEntity an actual class or your type parameter?

From what it looks to me TEntity is only the name of your type parameter, which I believe does not work.

you would need something like

```
class ConcreteNominationHibernateDAO
    extends BaseDao<ConcreteNominationSubclass> {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for Annotations @Entity,@Service, etc. Maybe you have missed something. So the DAO class cannot call the POJO Class and the bean can't be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Per the javadoc, `ParameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments` returns a `Type[]`. A `Type` is not necessarily a `Class` and therefore the cast to `Class` is not safe.

Per the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917733/error-testing-daos-sun-reflect-generics-reflectiveobjects-typevariableimpl-cann) by Piotr Findeisen:

> The expression

```
getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]
```

refers to value substituted to first type parameter of `AbstractHibernateDAO` (which in the `AbstractHibernateDAO.java` is denoted by `T`). The type substituted by subclass `NominationHibernateDAO` is still not concrete, it is `T extends Nomination`, which is definitely not a `java.lang.Class` instance, but a `Type` instance (`TypeVariableImpl` is an implementation of a `Type`).

If the `NominationHibernateDAO` was declared with something like that:

```
class NominationHibernateDAO extends AbstractHibernateDAO<Nomination, Integer> { ...
```

then the `AbstractHibernateDAO` constructor magic would work. Alternatively, you can (or you even should?) instantiate a subclass of `NominationHibernateDAO` declared like this:

```
class ConcreteNominationHibernateDAO
        extends NominationHibernateDAO<ConcreteNominationSubclass> { ...
```

or

```
new NominationHibernateDAO<ConcreteNominationSubclass>() {}
```

This, again, would not trigger the problem.

Are you sure the `NominationHibernateDAO` class is meant to be used as a Spring bean?